# Chrome Remote Desktop Doesn't Show Already Launched Apps

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop

I'm running Ubuntu Cosmic.  Suddenly, when logging into my Ubuntu machine via a Chrome Remote Desktop session, I see a "new desktop" (wallpaper + mouse) but not any of my existing launched applications. It's as if I was on a new tty.

Is there a way I can make it so that I can access my already launched applications from Chrome Remote Desktop? This was the behavior it exhibited a few months ago. I'm not sure what suddenly broke this (but the only thing I can think of is the update to Ubuntu Cosmic on my machine from Ubuntu Bionic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the instructions here worked for me (Ubuntu 18.04):

https://medium.com/@vsimon/how-to-install-chrome-remote-desktop-on-ubuntu-18-04-52d99980d83e

Basically you have to make chrome-remote-desktop use the existing X-session instead of creating a new one.